# Is it possible to get Visual Studio's Git interface to recognize a global ingnore?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I know that the IDE allows you to edit a local .gitignore file in the project. It also recognizes my email and name from the global config.

Is there a way to manually edit something so that it recognizes the settings that is already in the global config?

As a workaround I copied the global configuration file into .gitignore. After deleting ms-persist.xml and starting Visual Studio the desired values were there as part of the project.